# One Big Expression Containing Another Expressions

Tags: c#

I am new to expression tree and I am looking for a expression that may contain another expressions and may add those another expressions dynamically to itself at different places in my code.

Take a look at this example:

```
public void DoSomething()
{
   var ex1 = Expression.Call(....);

   // something else happens here

   var ex2 = Expression.Loop(...);

  // again something else

  foreach(var item in items)
  {
     var ex3 = Expression.And(...);
  }

  var everythingInOneExpression = .. // here I would like to have all expressions in one
}
```

As you can see in pseudo code, there are expressions being created, one of them is even inside a foreach and I would like to have all of them in the end inside one big expression.

Hard to explain but that big one is kinda a list that runs though its children expressions and executes them, or something like that. Except its not a list, its an expression. :)

Is there such a big expression thingy. I hope you can follow me on this one.

**Edit:**

The big one shall run though its items/expressions and execute them linking them with and operator.

Comment: And what's your question ? What should be the relations between your "sub expressions" in the "concatenated one" ?

Comment: The big one shall run though its subs and link them with and operator and execute them.

Comment: So just use `Expression.And` ?

Comment: Where would you use Expression.And? What do you mean? You might lose those expressions created in foreach.

Comment: Well something like `var finalExpression = Expression.And(ex1, Expression.And(ex2, Expression.And(ex3, ex4)))` By the way, if you wanna reuse an expression created in a foreach, you should declare it outside the loop.

Comment: Oh ok, I thought more of having a big one and in the end running though them executing and operator but this approach is also interesting. I will take a look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that PredicateBuilder is what you are looking for. Check [this](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx). If you want to dive into linq expression trees, you could see also [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb882637.aspx) MSDN reference.

Hope I helped!

Comment: Yea, this is awesome. I love the way the guy tricked out things. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Expression.Block` or `Expression.Lambda`, they can be created from list of Expressions.

Comment: Expression.Block cannot not be changed dynamically.